How to break an inline "minted" tcolorbox?
I need to break some inline tcolorboxes where I add some source code using minted. My MRE is presented below.
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    openright,
    twoside,
    a4paper,
    english,
    brazil
]{memoir}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc,soul,fourier}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,breakable,xparse}

\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=6

\setmintedinline{fontsize=\small}

\DeclareTotalTCBox{\inlineJavaCode}{ s v }{
    reset,
    listing only,
    on line,
    enhanced,
    nobeforeafter,
    tcbox raise base,
    boxrule=0.7pt,
    top=1mm,
    bottom=0mm,
    right=1mm,
    left=1mm,
    boxsep=0.5pt,
    before upper={\vphantom{dlg}},
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
    drop fuzzy shadow,
    arc=3pt}
{\mintinline{java}{#2}}%

\begin{document}
    
\selectlanguage{portuges}
\frenchspacing 

Whirring cogs of thought, spiraling through nebulae of consciousness. Quantum ripples
dance on the surface of perception, as ethereal beings weave tapestries of stardust 
\inlineJavaCode{public static int foo( int bar, int x, int y, int z, int y )}. In the 
labyrinthine corridors of time, echoes of forgotten futures reverberate, while the
scent of infinite possibilities fills the air.

\end{document}

The code example generates this:

But I want to generate something like this:

I found this question, Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX but I think that will not work for my problem, since I'm using minted. Do you know if theres a simple way to do this? If I break the inline box in two I will lose the syntax highlighting in some cases (not in this example):
Whirring cogs of thought, spiraling through nebulae of consciousness. Quantum ripples
dance on the surface of perception, as ethereal beings weave tapestries of stardust 
\inlineJavaCode{public static int foo( int bar, int x, int y, } \inlineJavaCode{int z, int y )}. 
In the labyrinthine corridors of time, echoes of forgotten futures reverberate, while
the scent of infinite possibilities fills the air.



Maybe this answer could help.
